# MongoDB / Mongoose query to find if an ID exist in another document , if exist add a flag in result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

### Problem definition:

We have 2 collections  `User` (where userdata is stored) & `UserTransactions` (where transactions done by users are stored). Users have 2 `usertypes` "parent" and "students".

**User Schema**

```
{
    _id : ---
    name : String
    usertype : String // parent/student
    studententity : [] // It will store _id of related students from same document
}
```

**UserTransaction Schema**

```
{
    _id : ---
    ref_id: // id of parent who is doing transaction
}
```

We need to obtain data comprising of

1. list of all parents
2. list of students under a parent
3. if a parent has done "any" transaction.

We can easily get 1st & 2nd condition by running the query

```
User.find({ "usertype": { $eq: "parent" } })
    .populate("studententity")
```

But we also want to get information about whether a parent has done "any" transaction. What is optimal way  to obtain this data?

My expected result looks like this

```
{
    "usertype": "parent",
    "studententity": [
        {
            "usertype": "student",
            "_id": "5f8a6d0900e0030c7031d56a",
            "name": "Adya"
        },
        { 
            "usertype": "student",
            "_id": "5f9bb96fdf44b931b40c6043",
            "name": "Aruja"
        }
    ],
    transactionflag : true // a flag that signifies transaction is done 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$lookup` and `$addFields` stages could be employed to get the desired result.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "transaction",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "ref_id",
      "as": "transactionflag"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "transactionflag": {
        $toBool: {
          $size: "$transactionflag"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/j0lL4uCgCtA